# crypto.js what does "ciphertext" mean

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

I am reading this article about crypto.js.

https://hibara.org/blog/2016/02/15/cryptojs/

```
text = "ABCDE"
password = "pass"

var secret_passphrase = crypto.enc.Utf8.parse(this.password);
    var salt = crypto.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8);
    var key128Bits500Iterations = crypto.PBKDF2(secret_passphrase, salt, {keySize: 128 / 8, iterations: 500 });
    var iv = crypto.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8);
    var options = {iv: iv, mode: crypto.mode.CBC, padding: crypto.pad.Pkcs7};
    var message_text = crypto.enc.Utf8.parse(this.text);
    var encrypted = crypto.AES.encrypt(message_text, key128Bits500Iterations, options);
    var binary_data = crypto.enc.Hex.stringify(salt);
    binary_data += (',' + crypto.enc.Hex.stringify(iv));
    binary_data += (',' + encrypted);

    console.log(binary_data)

    var array_rawData = binary_data.split(',');
    var salt = crypto.enc.Hex.parse(array_rawData[0]);
    var iv = crypto.enc.Hex.parse(array_rawData[1]);
    var encrypted_data = crypto.enc.Base64.parse(array_rawData[2]);
    var secret_passphrase = crypto.enc.Utf8.parse(this.password);
    var key128Bits500Iterations = crypto.PBKDF2(secret_passphrase, salt, {keySize: 128 / 8, iterations: 500 });
    var options = {iv: iv, mode: crypto.mode.CBC, padding: crypto.pad.Pkcs7};
    var decrypted = crypto.AES.decrypt({&quot;ciphertext&quot;:encrypted_data}, key128Bits500Iterations, options);

    console.log(decrypted)
```

But I am getting an error.

> Cannot find name 'ciphertext'.

and

> TS1005: ';' expected.

What is ciphertext ? 
Does anyone know the way to solve this problem?

---

Thank you so much for answering.

But it doesn't work properly.

I think console.log(decrypted) should be "ABCDE" , but I got WordArray object.

Do you know why?

---

```
text = "ABCDE"
  password = "pass"

var secret_passphrase = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(this.password);
      //alert(secret_passphrase.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
      var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8);
      var key128Bits500Iterations =
          CryptoJS.PBKDF2(secret_passphrase, salt, {keySize: 128 / 8, iterations: 500 });
      //初期化ベクトル（ブロック長と同じ）
      var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8);
      //暗号化オプション（IV:初期化ベクトル, CBCモード, パディングモード：PKCS7
      var options = {iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7};
      //暗号化内容のエンコーディングは「UTF-8」
      var message_text = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(this.text);

      //----------------------------------------------------------------------
      //暗号化
      var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message_text, key128Bits500Iterations, options);
      //----------------------------------------------------------------------

      //暗号結果データをカンマ（","）で結合してまとめる（復号時にわかるように）
      //（salt + iv + ciphertext)
      var binary_data = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(salt);
      binary_data += (',' + CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(iv));
      binary_data += (',' + encrypted);

      var array_rawData = binary_data.split(',');

      var salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(array_rawData[0]);  // パスワードSalt
      var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(array_rawData[1]);    // 初期化ベクトル（IV）
      var encrypted_data = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(array_rawData[2]); //暗号化データ本体

      //パスワード（鍵空間の定義）
      var secret_passphrase = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(this.password);
      var key128Bits500Iterations =
          CryptoJS.PBKDF2(secret_passphrase, salt, {keySize: 128 / 8, iterations: 500 });

      //復号オプション（暗号化と同様）
      var options = {iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7};

      //復号
      var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({"ciphertext":encrypted_data}, key128Bits500Iterations, options);
      // 文字コードをUTF-8にする
      console.log(decrypted)
```

I changed my code.

I thought inside of the decrypted would be "ABCDE" but inside of it there was WordArray object.

I want ABCDE back again do you know how to do that?

Comment: TS1005: ';' expected. is may be you missed(;) after console.log(decrypted)

Comment: BTW this is late 2018, maybe you should forget about cryptojs and learn the native Web Crypto straight away unless you have legacy code you can't afford to refactor. This is a good starting point: https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciphertext refers to the encrypted text.

As for the error you're getting: there's an encoding error in your code (and in the article you've copied it from).

This line:

```
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({&quot;ciphertext&quot;:encrypted_data}, key128Bits500Iterations, options);
```

Should be:

```
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({"ciphertext":encrypted_data}, key128Bits500Iterations, options);
```

Or even just:

```
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({ciphertext:encrypted_data}, key128Bits500Iterations, options);
```

The [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hibara/qzono8jb/) that the article links to has the correct code.

---

Complete snippet:

```js
const crypto = CryptoJS;
const text = "ABCDE"
const password = "pass"

var secret_passphrase = crypto.enc.Utf8.parse(password);
var salt = crypto.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8);
var key128Bits500Iterations = crypto.PBKDF2(secret_passphrase, salt, {keySize: 128 / 8, iterations: 500 });
var iv = crypto.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8);
var options = {iv: iv, mode: crypto.mode.CBC, padding: crypto.pad.Pkcs7};
var message_text = crypto.enc.Utf8.parse(text);
var encrypted = crypto.AES.encrypt(message_text, key128Bits500Iterations, options);
var binary_data = crypto.enc.Hex.stringify(salt);
binary_data += (',' + crypto.enc.Hex.stringify(iv));
binary_data += (',' + encrypted);

console.log(binary_data);

var array_rawData = binary_data.split(',');
var salt = crypto.enc.Hex.parse(array_rawData[0]);
var iv = crypto.enc.Hex.parse(array_rawData[1]);
var encrypted_data = crypto.enc.Base64.parse(array_rawData[2]);
var secret_passphrase = crypto.enc.Utf8.parse(password);
var key128Bits500Iterations = crypto.PBKDF2(secret_passphrase, salt, {keySize: 128 / 8, iterations: 500 });
var options = {iv: iv, mode: crypto.mode.CBC, padding: crypto.pad.Pkcs7};
var decrypted = crypto.AES.decrypt({ciphertext:encrypted_data}, key128Bits500Iterations, options);

console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/pbkdf2.js"></script>
```

Comment: or should it be var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({'ciphertext':encrypted_data}, key128Bits500Iterations, options);

Comment: @NarendraMongiya Doesn't matter. Makes no difference.

Comment: Thank you so much! But id doesn't worked properly. I think console.log(decrypted) should be "ABCDE" but I got WordArray object. Do you know why?

Comment: Works fine in the fiddle that I linked to in my answer. Probably better to base yourself on that.

Comment: Thank you so much but I want "ABCDE" again. I added code on my question.

Comment: I am so sorry I forgot to do "toStrging" thank you so much.

Comment: @nichika いえいえ :)